# Zoom API - Getting webinar participants/registrants for a recurrent webinar/meeting

Tags: zoom-sdk

I’ve created a code that calls Zoom API to get webinars’ participants/registrants’ data by "Webinar ID" and it works fine unless I'm calling a repeating webinars.

When calling for webinars that have multiple occurrences I get an error that the Webinar ID not exist.

I looked in the documentation and saw that for recurring events there should be a unique identifier for each occurrence but I can’t understand where or how to get it.

If anyone familiar with Zoom API, your assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The response from `/webinar` will return an array of all occurrences per the docs: https://developers.zoom.us/docs/api/rest/reference/zoom-api/methods/#operation/webinar

Each occurrence object in this array will have it's own unique id `occurrence_id`